# Swift SpriteKit contain nodes within screen width

Tags: swift, view

I have randomly spawning nodes moving vertically down the view.

Here is the code for doing this:

```
    let meteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "redmete.png")
    let movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.width)
    let meteOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) - self.frame.width / 2
    let meteTime = arc4random_uniform(4) + 3;
    let moveMete = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -2 * self.frame.height), duration: TimeInterval(meteTime))

    redmete = SKSpriteNode(texture: meteTexture)
    redmete.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX + meteOffset, y: self.frame.midY + self.frame.height / 2)
```

My only problem is that as the meteOffset uses the centre of the sprite therefore it can occasionally spawn so 50% or so is out of the view.

I have tried

```
let movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.width - meteTexture.size().width / 2)
```

I've also tried

```
let meteOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) - meteTexture.size().width / 2 - self.frame.width / 2
```

But neither keep the whole of the sprite within the view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will want the initial position to be between the sub range of your frame height that is inset by half the height of the meteor.

You would need to have :

```
let meteorHeight    = meteTexture.size().height 
let verticalRange   = self.frame.height - meteorHeight
let randomXPosition = meteorHeight/2  + arc4random() % verticalRange
```

Same goes for the horizontal position (if you want that to be random as well) :

```
let meteorWidth     = meteTexture.size().width 
let horizontalRange = self.frame.width - meteorWidth
let randomYPosition = meteorWidth/2  + arc4random() % horizontalRange
```

You can then set the position directly with the random XY coordinates

```
redmete.position = CGPoint(x:randomXPosition, y:randomYPosition)
```

If you don't want the meteor to appear too close to the edges, you can reduce the value of the verticalRange and horizontalRange further by subtracting a fixed offset or multiplying by a fraction.

Comment: It's failing on this line of code : let randomXPosition = meteorWidth / 2  + arc4random() % horizontalRange. "%" cannot be applied to operand of type "UInt32" and "CGFloat"

Comment: I didn't write the numeric type casting to keep the formula legible. You need to cast to CGFloat where appropriate.

Comment: I cast to CGFloat however this still didn't fix the problem. I've tried many combinations but can't get anything to work. If anything, it makes the nodes go further off screen at times

Comment: let randomXPosition = meteorHeight/2  + CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(verticalRange)) ...  it's rather ugly but since Swift thinks numbers aren't numbers, that's what we have to live with.

Comment: I've implemented everything with regard to horizontal position however I'm still getting nodes partly off screen. I've left the vertical as shown in original question as this is fine.

Comment: I just noticed I had my X and Y position variable reversed, did you notice and correct it in your code ?

Comment: Yes I reversed those. Check my above answer, it solved it but thank you Alain!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
let meteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "redmete.png")
    let movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.width / 2)
    let meteOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) + meteTexture.size().width/2 - self.frame.width / 2
    let meteTime = arc4random_uniform(4) + 3;
    let moveMete = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -2 * self.frame.height), duration: TimeInterval(meteTime))

    redmete = SKSpriteNode(texture: meteTexture)
    redmete.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX + meteOffset, y: self.frame.midY + self.frame.height / 2)
```